# Can I get the bluetooth data of vehicles in SUMO through traci?

Tags: sumo

I'm a new user of SUMO and TraCI. I have equipped vehicles with bluetooth in SUMO using configuration file. Now I wonder if I could get the bluetooth data using TraCI?(e.g. TraCI4matlab)

Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth devices in SUMO are just for (simulated) vehicle detection. There is no data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, how about loop detector, can I get the data from detector using traCI. Thanks a lot!